# Make ImageView appear within 2 seconds

Tags: android

I have an ImageView and I want it to appear 2 seconds after the code is run. I've tried this code but unfortunately it didn't do anything.

```
ImageView aniView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        float dest = 1;
        if (aniView.getAlpha() <= 0) {
            dest = 0;
            System.out.println("F");
        }
        ObjectAnimator animation3 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aniView,
                "alpha", dest);
        animation3.setDuration(5000);
        animation3.start();
```

Comment: Did you tried `setStartDelay(2000)`? Here is more information

http://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/07/android-objectanimator-delay.html

Comment: Why not just set a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for any `Handler`, `CountDownTimer` or any other direct thread manipulation.

Android built in classes like `ObjectAnimator` or `ViewPropertyAnimator` have all needed methods in their API.

Using `ObjectAnimator`:

```
  private static void showImageViewObjectAnimator(@NonNull final ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setAlpha(0f);
    final ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    objectAnimator.setStartDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
    objectAnimator.setDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
    objectAnimator.start();
  }
```

Using `ViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
  private static void showImageViewViewPropertyAnimator(@NonNull final ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setAlpha(0f);
    imageView.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setStartDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2))
        .setDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
    //no need to call start!
  }
```

I hope that it  helps you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right what you want is this...

Create a new layout file and name it splash (or whatever you want) and put that image there and then add this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
//display the image during 2 secondes,
new CountDownTimer(2000,1000){
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){} 

    @Override
    public void onFinish(){
           //set the new Content of your activity
           YourActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}.start();
//rest of the code goes here...
```

Comment: But image will appear abruptly, and I want it to appear slowly.

Comment: AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
anim.setDuration(2000);
yourImage.startAnimation(anim);

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 aniView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run()
            {
              // your code for animation.
            }
      }, 2000); //2000 for 2 seconds delay.
```

Comment: Will this appear abruptly?

Comment: Using that solution you are in responsibility of canceling this `Runnable` as well, be aware of that